# Extend and use a generic class in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In a React Typescript project, I'm trying to use a base class component, and also extend it with an extra property in State.

If I naively change it from

```
class ErrorBoundaryW extends PureComponent<any, State> {...}
```

to

```
class ErrorBoundaryW<SunState = {}> extends PureComponent<any, State & SunState> {...}
```

I get errors when trying to assign to State: 
[image]

How can I achieve this?

I'm aware that it is frowned upon in React to use inheritance besides extending the React's native Component and PureComponent [[source]](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html). But this is special case, an exception, and the only time I extended a custom React class Component.

Comment: Can you share the rest of that error and the code, as text and not an image?

Answer (score 1):

Typescript will never let you assign an object with a concrete type to an object that is of a type parameter. As an example of why this is problematic, the compiler can't check that all the required properties of the type parameter are present in the concrete type since the final type of the type parameter is not yet known. `SunState` could be `{ newProp: string }` so the `state` should have this property, yet the object literal does not have this property.

One option could be to use an abstract class and have an abstract method that creates the child state:

```
type State = {
    hasError: boolean
}
abstract class ErrorBoundaryW<SunState = {}> extends PureComponent<any, State & SunState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = Object.assign(this.childState(), {
            hasError: true
        });
    }
    abstract childState(): SunState
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because `this.state` might be of any possible type – your code in your class has no way of knowing what additional properties `SunState` adds, so it cannot safely assign any value to `this.state`.